# JMH: Constrain parameter space

Tags: jmh

Suppose I have a JMH test with two parameters:

```
@Param( { "1", "2", 4", "8", "16" } )
int param1;

@Param( { "1", "2", 4", "8", "16" } )
int param2;
```

Is there an idiomatic way to add a constraint on the parameters, e.g. only to benchmarks for `param1 < param2`?

Throwing an exception from an @SetUp works, but adds noise to the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, not at this point. If you feel the annotations are constraining, you can always fall back to the API. There, you can do something like:

```
for (int p1 = 1; p1 <= 16; p1 *= 2) {
   for (int p2 = 1; p2 <= p1; p2 *= 2) {
      Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
        ...
        .param("param1", p1)
        .param("param1", p2)
        .build();

       RunResult r = new Runner(opt).runSingle();
       ... put r somewhere to process
   }
}
```

(Maintainer's perspective: it does not seem worthwhile to wind up a full-fledged annotation-based DSL for JMH, it's just simpler to let users code their advanced scenarios in Java).

UPD: Come to think about it, you can probably encode both parameters into a single `@Param`, if you want to stay with the annotation-only way.

Comment: Thanks Aleksey - all makes sense. 

One simple approach might be a `SkipBenchmarksException` that could be thrown from an `@Setup` indicating that the current combination of parameters should be silently skipped.

Comment: This is similar to JUnit assumptions:
Assert.assumeThat(someBoolean,someMatcher);

Comment: `System.exit(0)` from `@Setup` works until `SkipBenchmarksException` is implemented